# How do I search for upscale self-service restaurants?

Tags: online-resources, food-and-drink, luxury

In Europe I'm a big fan of [Vapiano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapiano) restaurants. If you haven't heard of them, their concept is to combine the high(er) quality food of a regular restaurant with the self-service model of a buffet. This gets you your food faster and you don't have to tip anyone, which is especially important for North America where tips are around 15-20%.

But how do I search for such upper scale self-service places? A search for "fast food" usually returns McDonalds and Burger King, while a search for "self service restaurant" usually returns buffets which are a different concept. Or perhaps there's a website listing down chains like Vapiano, so that you could at least search for those chains while traveling?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may be looking for ['fast casual' restaurants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_casual_restaurant) whose Wikipedia entry even includes Vapiano. An alternative term is casual dining but that would usually refer to a place with table service.

If there's any table service in a fast casual place, it'll be limited to bringing the food you ordered to the table or removing dishes. I (US native) might tip 10% or a few dollars in that case but it's not standard. The restaurant may have a tip jar at the counter so you  can tip (or not) when you order.

Here's Wikipedia's [list of fast casual restaurants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Fast_casual_restaurants).

Comment: Don't leave money at the table, unless you intend to leave it for me.  They may not come round ot bus the tables for an hour.  There is indeed a tip jar at the cashier. Also unfortunately "fast casual" is not that useful a google word, because the search result list is being vandalized by McDonalds, Taco Bell, Wendys, Arbys and other "cheap food in a sack" tier restaurants, who want to believe they too are part of the "fast casual" market, often with a few upscale items grafted onto their menu.

Comment: @Harper all true but leaving a tip on a table and having it stolen by another customer could happen anywhere. Stick it under a plate if you're worried.

Comment: I'm saying at a fast casual restaurant, that wouldn't even be stealing.  **Because there is no table service at all**; when staff comes out and buses abandoned tables, that is not table service, that is tidying up the restaurant because people are pigs.

Comment: I understand. I'm thinking of Panera where you can order from a table, or if you order hot food, someone brings it to your table. It's still casual and fast but it's a step up from hang around the counter waiting for your food. I said the tipping wasn't usual. I'm so happy to have never had to work food service that I tend to be generous tipping. I tip when I get take out food from a regular restaurant too.

Comment: Yeah, that thing where you can order food on your iPad off their website from a Panera table is kind of an anomaly.  Actually they "run" at my McDonalds too, when you order at the kiosk you take a "table card" that is electronic *that geolocates you within the restaurant* so a runner knows where to find you.  That doesn't mean you tip at McDonalds and you still have to bus your tray.